# FileNotFound Error while converting docx2pdf

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, docx2pdf

im trying to make a python program that converts docx files to pdf using flask. But i get an Error like this:
[image]

Below I paste code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template, send_file
import os
from typing import Tuple
from docx2pdf import convert

UPLOADER_FOLDER = ''
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOADER_FOLDER'] = UPLOADER_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        def docx2pdf(input_file: str, output_file: str, pages: Tuple = None):
           if pages:
               pages = [int(i) for i in list(pages) if i.isnumeric()]

           result = convert(input_file, output_file)
           print('Convert Done')
           summary = {
               "File": input_file, "Pages": str(pages), "Output File": output_file
            }
           print("\n".join("{}:{}".format(i, j) for i, j in summary.items()))
           return result
        file = request.files['filename']
        if file.filename!= '':
           file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADER_FOLDER'], file.filename))
           input_file = file.filename
           output_file = r"hello.pdf"
           docx2pdf(input_file, output_file)
           pdf = input_file.split(".")[0]+".pdf"
           print(pdf)
           lis=pdf.replace(" ", "=")
           os.rename("hello.pdf", lis)
           print('converted')
           return render_template("docx.html", variable=lis)
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/docx', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def docx():
    if request.method=="POST":
        lis = request.form.get('filename', None)
        lis = lis.replace("=", " ")
        return send_file(lis, as_attachment=True)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Can any one help? This is my last post for further details:
[FileNotFoundError docx to pdf convert program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770737/filenotfounderror-docx-to-pdf-convert-program)

Comment: set the root directory as base directory, you code is fine, its just not able to find the file at the folder its looking for, try and print the paths, you will get the idea on why its not working.
use this to point to the root of the app:
`basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score 0):

As we can see there

```py
if file.filename!= '':
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADER_FOLDER'], file.filename))
    input_file = file.filename
    output_file = r"hello.pdf"
    docx2pdf(input_file, output_file)
    pdf = input_file.split(".")[0]+".pdf"
    print(pdf)
    lis=pdf.replace(" ", "=")
    os.rename("hello.pdf", lis)
    print('converted')
    return render_template("docx.html", variable=lis)
```

You try to convert file. But you use `docx2pdf(input_file, output_file)`. And if you look at the import section, you can see this

```py
from docx2pdf import convert
```

So, you don't use `convert` -> file not saved and processed -> `FileNotFoundError`